# How many queens are needed to attack all white squares?

Tags: chess, optimization, checkerboard

This question: [How can 3 queens control the white squares?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/107107/how-can-3-queens-control-the-white-squares) got me thinking...

What is the fewest number of queens needed to attack every white square?
Rules:

- Only queens allowed
- Every white square is attacked — not just occupied
- No queen attacks another queen

Comment: What do you mean by "attacked — not just occupied"? Every white square must be attacked, regardless of whether it's occupied or not? Or white squares can't be occupied?

Comment: That was to clarify vs the linked question. In that question, it was enough for a queen to be on a white square (occupy). This question requires attacking all white squares.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong (I probably am), but rule #2 and #3 makes it seem like queens can only be on black squares. All white squares must be attacked (not just occupied), meaning if a queen was on a white square, another queen would have to attack it, which breaks rule #3. If a queen is on a black square and we only care about attacking white squares, we only need to care about it's diagonal movement if it's attacking another queen, which would yield a possible solution like the naive symmetrical approach like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpktM.png)

Comment: Your interpretation of rules #2 and #3 are correct. It seemed like explicitly stating that made the starting point too easy.

Comment: @LukasRotter I was thinking that too ... but then I think there's no difference between queens and rooks, for the purposes of this problem?

Comment: I have found many solutions using only rooks. The majority of those fail for queens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The minimum is

> 4 queens:
> \begin{matrix}&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.\\&.&.&.&.&Q&.&.&.\\&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.\\&Q&.&.&.&.&.&.&.\\&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.\\&.&.&.&.&.&.&Q&.\\&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.\\&.&.&Q&.&.&.&.&.\\\end{matrix}

Comment: Damn it, was just about to post my answer xD +1

Comment: The reason I actually made the question is that this is the only solution I could find.

Comment: The solution is unique up to symmetry.