# Attacking queens

Tags: combinatorics, chess

Can you place 3 queens on a 6x6 chess board such that they can attack every square?

Good luck!

Comment: Related: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/22/how-many-chess-pieces-does-it-take-to-cover-all-spaces-on-a-chessboard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the solution:

> [image: three queens]

It's interesting to note that the [domination problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_chess_problem#Domination_problems) has very few solutions for [3 queens on a 6x6 chessboard](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QueensProblem.html) as compared to other possibilities. (Neither of those links contains the answer! Just background info.)

Perhaps the key realisation is that

> some squares which you'd intuitively expect to be attacked diagonally can be attacked orthogonally. With one queen at $a1$ covering the central white diagonal, it'd seem natural to use two more to cover the black diagonals to either side, including those difficult squares $b3/c2$ and $e6/f5$. But putting the other two queens on the next diagonals leaves not enough space to reach out to the edges ... and we realise there's a nice configuration to cover $b3/c2$ and $e6/f5$ orthogonally.

Before that, starting with

> a queen at the corner is a counterintuitive move in which I was inspired by the [5 queens on an 8x8 chessboard](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/22/5373) problem.

Comment: Nice! I was trying to prove that you can't :)

Comment: @ArnaudMortier It turns out "proving that you can't" is surprisingly difficult for domination problems. For the 8x8 chessboard, there is no known 'nice' proof that it can't be done with 4 queens; that was proved by brute-forcing every case.

Comment: In this case it seemed that counting the appropriate kind of squares would do the trick (e.g. side squares that are of the opposite colour to the queen's square, etc).

Comment: Great solution. I wasn't able to find any other solutions. Can we prove that this is the only one?

Comment: @Dmitry According to [the MathWorld link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QueensProblem.html), there is exactly one arrangement in which all the queens are 'protected' by each other. Which isn't this one, so it's not unique.