# Attacking queens revisited

Tags: combinatorics, chess

Can you place 5 queens on a 11x11 chess board such that they can attack every empty square?

It turns out this problem was answered here:
http://golovolomka.hobby.ru/books/gik/04.shtml

Can you find another solution?

Good luck with this!

Comment: Related https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/89117/62537

Comment: Added "attack empty squares"

Comment: If you already know about related puzzles, rather than including them in a comment you might consider adding them directly into the body of the puzzle and save comment space for commenters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes:** the solution was already mentioned in [this answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/60/5373), sourced to [this page](http://golovolomka.hobby.ru/books/gik/04.shtml).

> [image: up to 11x11]

Comment: I'm not sure if that makes this question a duplicate or not: it wasn't *asked* on the other thread, but was *answered* there.

Comment: Can you find another solution?